# Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord

Tags: android

my Android application generates this warning:

> 06-30 14:43:17.863:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(590): Timeout of
>   broadcast BroadcastRecord{437385d8
>   android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} -
>   receiver=android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@436d0960
>   06-30 14:43:18.664:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(590): Receiver
>   during timeout:
>   BroadcastFilter{436d0b80
>   ReceiverList{436d0b08 590 system/1000
>   client 436d0960}} 06-30 14:43:32.533:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(590):
>   finishReceiver called but no pending
>   broadcasts

Someone can tell me what that means?
In my application there are a lot of active thread.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is that you are doing some heavy processing in the `onReceive()` method of a `BroadcastReceiver`. Your `onReceive()` should typically just kick off a `Service` and then return, and any processing is done in your `Service`. My guess is that your `onReceive()` is taking too long to complete, resulting in this error. Read the section on [Receiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) for more information.

Comment: THANKS!!!!
I haven't BroadcastReceiver. I have some thread that execute heavy java code, particulary WEKA's data mining algorithms! the strange thing is that I have the same application running on 5 different machines, but only on one machine I have this problem! could be a problem related to the properties of the machines?

Comment: I also noted that, in the log file, is often printed the following line:
`threadid=17: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is that the cpu is busy and binder call failed.

so the broadcast can not be dispatched quickly.